# Joint PMF and Covariance of two dice rolls

Tags: random-variables

Two fair dice are cast. Let X denote the sum of the values that turn up and let Y denote the absolute value of their difference.

I'm having trouble coming up with the joint pmf of X and Y. Any advice on how to visualize the problem?

Comment: Create tables of values: 2 die with $X$ values, 2 die with $Y$ values, then finally $X$ vs $Y$ values from the previous tables.

Comment: @0XLR : Except that "die" is singular and "dice" is plural.

Comment: $$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
1 & (2,0) & (3,1) & (4,2) & (5,3) & (6,4) & (7,5) \\
2 & (3,1) & (4,0) & (5,1) & (6,2) & (7,3) & (8,4) \\
3 & (4,3) & (5,2) & (6,0) & (7,2) & (8,2) & (9,3) \\
4 & (5,3) & (6,2) & (7,1) & (8,0) & (9,1) & (10,2) \\
5 & (6,4) & (7,3) & (8,2) & (9,1) & (10,0) & (11,1) \\
6 & (7,5) & (8,3) & (9,3) & (10,2) & (11,1) & (12,0)
\end{array}
$$